# Использование классов из /target

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я использую JOOQ. JOOQ генерирует метаклассы, которые потом используются для генерации запросов в базу. Окей. Рекомендуется генерировать классы в `/target/generated-sources/jooq..`. Сгенерировал. Но когда я пытаюсь вызвать этот класс в коде, IDEA не видит эти классы.

Подскажите, как мне быть?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно выделить метаклассы в отдельную библиотеку. В одном модуле maven классы генерируются, в других модулях этот модуль проставляется как зависимость и используются сгенерированные метаклассы.

При таком подходе модель базы автоматически отделяется от бизнес-логики.

> Рекомендуется генерировать классы в `/target/generated-sources/jooq`

Это так, но в документации есть раздел ([Code generation and version control](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-version-control/)) в котором вопрос генерации освещается подробнее. Разделяются два общих подхода:

1. Генерированный код является частью кода приложения.

   Метаклассы генерируются в исходном коде (`src/main/java`), хранятся в системе контроля версий. Генерация проводится, как правило, вручную, а не при сборке, т.к. возможны изменения.

   Преимущества:

   - Генерация отделена от сборки. Для сборки проекта не нужна БД.
   - Метаклассы не зависят от БД. Это может быть удобно если схема БД изменяется внешними силами (например, другими разработчиками).
   - Изменения схемы БД явно хранятся в системе контроля версий.

   Недостатки:

   - Метаклассы могут расходиться с базой данных.
2. Генерированный код является частью производных артефактов.

   Метаклассы генерируются в процессе сборки автоматически (`target/generated`), не хранятся в системе контроля версий.

   Преимущества:

   - Модель данных всегда соответствует БД.
   - Метаклассы не занимают место в исходном коде.

   Недостатки:

   - Сборка зависит от базы данных.

Как правило используют второй подход, чтобы избежать разночтений между БД и Java-кодом, но при необходимости можно использовать как первый подход, так и некое промежуточное решение.

В любом случае метаклассы лучше хранить отдельно.